# "TypeError: user.send is not a function" in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am developing a discord bot in discord.js.
This error appeared when sending a direct message to a user.
here is my code:(code.js)

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const options = { intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] };
const client = new Client(options);

client.on("ready", (message) => {
console.log("ready！");
> });


let user = client.users.fetch('User_ID')
user.send("hello!")

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const querystring = require("node:querystring");

//GASでwakeさせること。

http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == "POST") {
      var data = "";
      req.on("data", function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
      });
      req.on("end", function() {
        if (!data) {
          res.end("No post data");
          return;
        }
        var dataObject = querystring.parse(data);
        console.log("post:" + dataObject.type);
        if (dataObject.type == "wake") {
          console.log("Woke up in post");
          res.end();
          return;
        }
        res.end();
      });
    } else if (req.method == "GET") {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
      res.end("Discord Bot is Oprateing!");
    }
  })
  .listen(3000);

if (process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN == undefined || process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN == "") {
  console.log("Can you set the DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN?。");
  process.exit(0);
}

require("./code.js")
```

Error message:

> TypeError: user.send is not a function
> at Object. (/app/code.js:12:7)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at Object. (/app/server.js:39:1)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)

I thought I was not getting user IDs, so I changed from "`client.users.fetch('ID')`" to "`client.users.cache.get('ID')`" this code.
result:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

The code "client.users.fetch('ID')" has been changed to the following code.

```
client.users.send('User_ID', 'content');
```

Result :

> /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/UserManager.js:58
> const data = await this.client.api.users(this.client.user.id).channels.post({
> ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
> at UserManager.createDM (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/UserManager.js:58:63)
> at UserManager.send (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/UserManager.js:114:24) at
> Object. (/app/code.js:10:14)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) at Object. (/app/server.js:39:1)

Answer (score 0):

The `client.users.fetch()` function returns a promise, not a user. You'll need to resolve the promise before you can actually use the `User` object to send a message.

You can either do this with `.then()` or `async/await` (I'm sure you can look these up to find more information).

Also, you need to call `client.login()` before you try to do anything.

Here's how to do it with `.then()`:

```js
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);

client.users.fetch('User_ID').then(user => {
    user.send("hello!")
})
```